# Efeito JS deslizar div e aparecer outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação, greensock-gsap

Seguinte tenho uma home aonde o usuário vai se deparar com um campo para login ou um botão para se cadastrar. Ao clicar no botão cadastrar gostaria que esse conteúdo atual sumisse da tela deslizando para esquerda e o proximo card (etapa) de cadastrado aparecesse deslizando da direita e parando no meio.

Alguém tem algum link com exemplos de preferência com GSAP ou algum outro plugin. Só preciso de alguma referencia para adaptar ao meu projeto.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, creio que seja algo assim...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-cadastrar").click(function() {
        $('#div-login').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $('#div-cadastro').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```